# Use an arrow assignment function as R purrr map2

Tags: r, lapply, raster, purrr

I have a list of rasters:

```
filelist <- as.list(c("rasterA", "rasterB") # name them
rasterlist <- lapply(filelist, function(x) raster::raster(x)) # read them in
```

And a list of CRSes corresponding to those rasters:

```
crslist <- as.list(c("crsA.Rds", "crsB.Rds")) # name them
crslist %<>% lapply(function(x) readRDS(x)) # read them in
```

To fill the `@crs` slot in a raster you use (e.g.):

```
raster::crs(rasterA) <- crsA
```

But I can't work out how to use this arrow assignment in a `purrr::map2` call. The example in the R cheat sheet is `map2(x, y, sum)`, but sum works on vectors, is directionless, and contains all of its terms within its brackets.

Reading the map2 help, I tried the formula format:

```
purrr::map2(rasterlist, crslist, ~ raster::crs(.x) <- .y)
```

But no dice:

> Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : object '.y' not found

Does anyone know how I'd do this? Currently I'm using a loop which is simple, but I'm trying to force myself to learn mapping and keep hitting these kinds of walls.

```
for (i in length(rasterlist)) {
 crs(rasterlist[[i]]) <- crslist[[i]]
}
```

Thanks!

Starting condition:

[image: NA crs]

After for loop:

[image: forloop]

After raster_assigner function instead:

[image: rasterassigner]

Hopefully this is salvagable because I've got other use cases like this. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may need

```
purrr::map2(rasterlist, crslist, ~ {crs(.x) <- .y;.x})
```

It is not related to the `raster` - as the simple example below shows the same error

```
> map2(list(1, 2, 3), list(3, 4, 5), ~ names(.x) <- .y)
Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : object '.y' not found
> map2(list(1, 2, 3), list(3, 4, 5), ~ {names(.x) <- .y; .x})
[[1]]
3 
1 

[[2]]
4 
2 

[[3]]
5 
3
```

However this won't return an error in `Map` (but it is not correct because the output returned is without the names, unless we wrap it with `{}` and return the `x`

```
> Map(function(x, y) names(x) <- y, list(1, 2, 3), list(3, 4, 5))
[[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
[1] 4

[[3]]
[1] 5
```

Comment: Great success! So I can conceive what the curly brackets are doing (though I'm not used to them in this context); what function does the semicolon serve here? Cheers!

Comment: @dez93_2000 the `;` is to separate the expressions.  The `crs(.x) <- .y` is first expression,,and then we need to return the .x object which is second expression.  When there are more one expression, we use `{}`.  if we want to separate multiple expressions within a single line, use the `;` to specify the end of line.  Or else, I could have added the second expression as  a new line without the `;`

Comment: Thanks akrun. Hopefully a followup's ok, as it's directly related to this question and your example. I'm also looking to name the individual rasters within the list, but the same code as yours doesn't seem to work - details given in question. Thanks again.

Comment: @dez93_2000 did you meant the `map2(list(1, 2, 3), list(3, 4, 5), ~ {names(.x) <- .y; .x})`  It is just an example to name the vectors inside the `list` and not the `raster` name.  If you check the docs, `r <- raster(ncols=5, nrows=5);
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r);
s <- stack(r, r, r);
nlayers(s);
names(s);
names(s) <- c('a', 'b', 'c')` it is done like this example

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, wrote out a whole example in the edit then realised it had worked after all! I was looking for the `names(rasterlist)` to change but it's the `names(rasterlist[[1]])` which should and did change. Out of interest, how DO you set names(listobject) in a pipe? I've tried & failed with lapply but maybe lapply is too deep, i.e. within the list objects, and names() is top level, naming those objects? Thanks again.

Comment: @dez93_2000 you can use `setNames` i.e. `map2(list(1, 2, 3), list(3, 4, 5),  ~ .x %>% setNames(.y))` (not tested with `raster` though) or may also use the setter function `map2(list(1, 2, 3), list(3, 4, 5),  ~ "names<-"(.x, .y))`

Comment: Fabulous, thanks. Those approaches name the individual list element objects rather than the list 'numbers' (which is still useful), but the setNames function is new to me, and that's what's needed in pipe: `datalist %<>% setNames(nameslist)`. Thanks, as always!

Answer (score 3):

Could do a dedicated function:

```
raster_assigner <- function(raster, crs_input){
  raster::crs(raster) <- crs_input
  raster
}
purrr::map2(rasterlist, crslist, raster_assigner)
```

Comment: Thanks. Neat solution but instead of populating the empty `crs` slot, it populates the whole list object with the crs value. See images in updated question.

Comment: You have a syntax bug in your for loop. `for (i in length(rasterlist))` should be `for (i in 1:length(rasterlist))`. I also missed the return statement in the function, should work now.